# htaccess when I go to any directory provides Object not found! Error 404

Tags: .htaccess

I need redirect `/` to `/pages/`
but when i go to `/pages/diplom/` or other directory `/pages/**/`
Object not found error 404

Code below:

```
DirectoryIndex /pages/index.php

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f

RewriteRule ^(.+) $1 [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/pages/%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^(.+) /pages/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.